# Unable to create Cache for Large Vector

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, geowebcache, vector-layer, large-datasets

I have uploaded a large vector data (20 million records) to Postgres; published the data on Geoserver. But, when I try to create cache for the same it throws GC overhead limit exceeded error.
I have tried increasing the java heap size to 8GB with the following parameter `"-Xms1024M -Xmx8192M -d64"` in the Java console. Tried to create cache again but failed.
I have added the log of the Geoserver and Geoserver status image

```
06 Dec 08:03:30 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-1 begins seeding layer : GEO:fz_2016
06 Dec 08:03:30 WARN [layer.MetaTile] - ********* Native JAI is not installed, meta tile cropping may be slow ********
06 Dec 08:03:30 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
06 Dec 08:03:30 WARN [operation.projection] - Possible use of "Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator" projection outside its valid area.
Longitude 181░24.4'W is out of range (▒180░).
Latitude 91░24.4'S is out of range (▒90░).
06-Dec-2017 08:11:26.670 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run Unexpected death of background thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.getBytes(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:674)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5451)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1366)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.getBytes(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:674)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5451)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1366)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
06 Dec 08:11:45 ERROR [geotools.rendering] - GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement.toString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:60)
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:826)
        at org.geotools.util.logging.Log4JLogger.log(Log4JLogger.java:130)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.fireErrorEvent(StreamingRenderer.java:490)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.access$800(StreamingRenderer.java:182)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PaintShapeRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3247)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3572)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
06 Dec 08:11:46 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering process failed
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:595)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:278)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:141)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:653)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:285)
        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:131)
        at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:80)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.getMap(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:857)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1284)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:635)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:579)
        at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:774)
        at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:141)
        at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
        at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
        at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.fireErrorEvent(StreamingRenderer.java:496)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.access$800(StreamingRenderer.java:182)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3581)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement.toString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:60)
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:826)
        at org.geotools.util.logging.Log4JLogger.log(Log4JLogger.java:130)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.fireErrorEvent(StreamingRenderer.java:490)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.access$800(StreamingRenderer.java:182)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PaintShapeRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3247)
        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3572)
        ... 5 more
```

[image: Geoserver status]

Comment: What version of GeoServer is that?

Comment: It is Geoserver 2.12.0 and Geowebcache 1.12.0